# sorting the array values which are get from dictionary in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I need to sort the array values which are get from the dictionary . I need to sort it based on key or values .

i have tried the code

```
var Dictionary = [Int : String]()
Dictionary  = [1: "pandi" , 2 : "nashrin" , 3 :"vanji"]
print(Dictionary)

var dicarray = [[Int :String]]()
dicarray = [Dictionary]
print(dicarray)
let dictKeyInc = dicarray.sorted(by: <)
print(dictKeyInc)
```

but i was not able to sort .

Comment: Are you want to sort it by keys value?

Comment: want to sort the values in array in anyway

Comment: There is nothing to sort, your array contains only 1 element. If you have many dictionaries what do you want to sort by?

Comment: Can you show the expected result for the dictionary `[1: "pandi" , 2 : "nashrin" , 3 :"vanji"]`? And ideally you should show more examples of expected inputs and outputs.

Comment: First of all need  assign the values from dictionary to array . And the need to sort the elements in an array in any way . name of the array is assigned as "dicarray"

Answer (score -1):

Please use this.

```
Dictionary.sorted { (obj1, obj2) -> Bool in
   return obj1.key < obj2.key
}
```

Comment: i want sort the array values not dictionary values . name of the array is  dicarray